# Read and print text file from HDFS

Tags: c++, hadoop

I have this short code that read bytes from a text file on the Hadoop File System (HDFS) using [libhdfs](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/LibHdfs.html). It compiles and works fine. I am now trying to change the code so I could read a the content of the text file as well.

The following is the code I have right now for printing a text file from HDFS:

```
#include "jni.h"
#include "hdfs.h"
#include "string.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  int MAXBUFLEN = 1024;

  hdfsFS fs = hdfsConnect("default", 0);
  const char* readPath = "/tmp/testfile.txt";
  hdfsFile readFile = hdfsOpenFile(fs, readPath, O_RDONLY, 0, 0, 0);
  if(!readFile) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open %s for writing!\n", readPath);
    exit(-1);
  }
  char buffer[MAXBUFLEN+1];

  int bytes = hdfsRead(fs, readFile, buffer, strlen(buffer));
  buffer[MAXBUFLEN] = '\0';
  hdfsCloseFile(fs, readFile);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: writing honestly, here you are not remotely accessing a file but locally. you are just reading the local single node cluster files created through hadoop on your hard disk, for reading and writing the files, you simply google it and have a practice on it, happy coding... :)

Comment: @ArifMustafa thank you for your answer. I am aware that I am not remotely accessing a file, that is not the intention either. I just want to access and read files that are on my HDFS trough C++ locally in the same Hadoop environment (which is a Hortonworks Sandbox). If you take a look at the the Sample Program at https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/LibHdfs.html - you will see an example of locally writing to HDFS, I want to do exactly the same but read instead and print.

Comment: See, it doesn't mean you are accessing a hadoop cluster, you are still on local environment, either you are on host os such windows, linux, macox or using a guest os through virtualbox, vmware wrkstn. player, Hyper-V. Bro simply put a textfile near you class file, and try to practice on it, see this link https://www.codesdope.com/cpp-file-io/ and have a practice on it, if found helpful, mark it, thanks.

Comment: You are missing the brief. Yes, I am on a host (Linux), from where I execute the example. The example that is presented on the libhdfs page, now also edited into my post, is accessing my local Hadoop Distributed File System. Are you with me? So now, I want to remake it in order to read and output the text file instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should initialize your buffer this way:

```
char buffer[MAXBUFLEN+1] = {};
```

then pass the maximum buffer length (don't use `strlen`) to the read function:

```
int bytes = hdfsRead(fs, readFile, buffer, MAXBUFLEN);
```

No need of this line:

```
buffer[MAXBUFLEN] = '\0';
```

since the buffer is properly initialized. You can then output the whole buffer as a c string:

```
std::cout << buffer << std::endl;
```

The string length, now, should be equal to the read bytes:

```
assert(strlen(buffer)==bytes);
```

Comment: This is perfect, tested it, working just like I wanted. I can now print text files from my local HDFS with C++. I just had to change the [MAXBUFLEN+1] to [1024] directly as the int MAXBUFLEN = 1024 and char buffer[MAXBUFLEN+1] = {} gives error when compiling as (C++/g++): variable-sized object ‘buffer’ may not be initialized". Many thanks for your help!!